# How to load the html content of a URL to a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP GET request in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

I have a url that contains a XML tree. I want to read that url content, save it to a variable, extract XML tree values, and draw it in a table.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AJAX query, in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(data) {
     // Data is your xml content which you can work with
  }
});
```

Comment: i have written that code , but there is no sense                             <head> <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {      
       $.ajax({
            url: 'www.google.com',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (data) {
                // Data is your xml content which you can work with
                alert(url);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>